# How to Get all Similar kind of words in a sentence into an array

Tags: java

I have a String

```
String sentence = "I tried to speak @ty Spanish @ty-1, and my@ty-2 friend tried to@ty-3 speak English @ty.";
```

I want all words @ty, @ty-1.. etc into an ArrayList. @ty words are dynamic, keeps changing in different scenarios as shown above.

Result should be like :- arrayList should contain the elements
`[@ty, @ty-1, @ty-2, @ty-3, @ty]` for the above sentence.

How can it be done?

Comment: @hjpotter92 can I ve the full code?

Comment: No, you should get the basics clear about how regexes are implemented in Java on your own.

Comment: @PRATHAPS - If you are looking for a REGEX solution, try my answer ::P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why `regex`? You can try something like this

```
  String sentence = "I tried to speak @ty Spanish @ty-1, and my@ty-2 friend tried to@ty-3 speak English @ty.";
  String[] arr=sentence.replaceAll(",","").split(" ");
  List<String> list=new ArrayList<>();
  for(String i:arr){
     if(i.contains("@")){
         list.add(i.substring(i.indexOf("@"),i.length()));
      }
    }
  System.out.println(list);
```

Output:

```
  [@ty, @ty-1, @ty-2, @ty-3, @ty]
```

Comment: Yes but if there is no space like 'my@ty-2' in the sentence?

Comment: I did not notice that properly, THank you

Answer (score 1):

You can use reges :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String sentence = "I tried to speak @ty Spanish @ty-1, and my@ty-2 friend tried to@ty-3 speak English @ty.";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(@ty.*?)(?=[,\\s+\\.])");
        Matcher m = p.matcher(sentence);
        while (m.find()) {
            System.out.println(m.group());
        }
    }
```

O/P :

```
@ty
@ty-1
@ty-2
@ty-3
```

Comment: Yes This will work, But what was wrong with my question?

Comment: Oh I wasn't knowing about putting my code which I've tried with.

Comment: @PRATHAPS - You should *always* put code in your question.. So that people will know that you have tried.

Comment: Sure from next time I'll, And Thanks for your suggestion , I mean it.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
Pattern pattern=Pattern.compile("@ty[-\\W][0-9]*");
Matcher matcher=pattern.matcher(sentence);

while(matcher.find())
{
    System.out.println(matcher.group());
}
```